# Why does my file close?

Tags: python

For some reason my file seems unable to be accessed after i invoke readlines()
Any idea why?

The main concern is that the for-loop after doesn't work. It doesn't iterate through the lines.

```
with open('wordlist.txt') as fHand:
    content = fHand.readlines()

    lines = 0

    for _ in fHand:
        lines += 1
```

Comment: I think you want `for _ in content:`?

Comment: Or use `len(content)` right away, if you just care about the number of lines and don't need to process them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fHand.readlines()` reads the whole file, so your file pointer is at the end of the file.

If you really want to do this (hint: you probably don't) you can add `fHand.seek(0)` before the `for` loop to move the pointer back to the beginning of the file.

```
with open('wordlist.txt') as fHand:
    content = fHand.readlines()
    fHand.seek(0)

    lines = 0
    for _ in fHand:
        lines += 1
```

---

In general, the `.read*` commands are not what you're looking for when you're looking at files in Python. In your case you should probably do something like:

```
words = set()  # I'm guessing

with open("wordlist.txt") as fHand:
    linecount = 0
    for line in fHand:
        # process line during the for loop
        # because honestly, you're going to have to do this anyway!
        # chances are you're stripping it and adding it to a `words` set? so...
        words.add(line.strip()
        linecount += 1
```

Comment: Solved my problem :) Thanks for the help!